# Help solving a error in openGL

Tags: opengl, macos

I am making a group work in openGL, and when i try to open the file that my partner gave me i have this error:

-------------- Build: Debug in CG ---------------

Linking console executable: bin/Debug/CG
ld: library not found for -lGL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings

I've seen the same code working in his computer.
Is it cause he is working in Windows? and i am working in MacOSX? I am using CodeBlocks IDE.

Can anyone help me solving this?

Comment: Thats not a compile error, its a link error.

Comment: thanks for correcting me. do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I use linux, not mac, so I'm not sure what the correct flag is on a Mac. Sorry. However, I do recommend checking that you have installed the correct library.

Answer (score 9):

The OpenGL library is actually a Framework on MacOSX.

It should link correctly if you replace `-lGL` by `-framework OpenGL`.

Comment: Now I am working in Xcode, and I've imported the framework OpenGL, and i have the g++ 4.1 version but I still have error:

Command /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.0 failed with exit code 1

Comment: There is this error message:
duplicate symbol _main in 


/Users/leonor/Desktop/CG2010/Proj/build/Proj.build/Debug/Proj.build/Objects-normal/i386/Tp.o and /Users/leonor/Desktop/CG2010/Proj/build/Proj.build/Debug/Proj.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o

It says that is something about the debug configuration.
do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You have 2 main functions in your code/project. You should have only 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the below, as jweyrich said, OpenGL is a framework in Mac OS X:

```
gcc -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -o test test.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the actual library, and that `-lGL` is the correct flag. The name of the library may be different on your system.