# Compiling lsd_slam on OS X throws linking error ld: library not found for -lGL

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, slam-algorithm

I am trying to compile lsd_slam on OSX 10.9.5 and I get the build error as

```
ld: library not found for -lGL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

From what I understand from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3026629/229341), it needs to compile with the flag`-framework OpenGL`. What changes are needed and in which Makefile so as this choses the framework instead of -lGL.

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? I'm also facing similar trouble!

Comment: Nope. I was unable to move past this. I could not try lsd_slam for this reason. My purpose got fulfilled by OpenMVG.

Answer (score 2):

It should link correctly if you replace `-lGL` by `-framework OpenGL`